# Python: How to do statistical calculations on big 2D numpy arrays using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multiprocessing, out-of-memory

To start with, I am fairly new here and I hope I manage to clearly describe the problem, if not I can provide more code or information.
 I am working with Python 2.7 and information derived from satellite images, represented by a number of numpy arrays. So every value in my array represents an information for a specific pixel position in my image. I have two array-sets (vegetation index, and rainfall rate) - each consisting of 17 arrays - data from 17 years.
Now I want to process statistics on these fairly big numpy arrays. 
 
So far so good. I implemented that and tested it successfully for a small test area but running my code on the full image extent i get a **MemoryError**. That leads me to my actual question, because I am having **trouble with Pythons multiprocessing tool.** My initial thought was to segment my image and do the calculations tile by tile.

Lets say I have an image with the size 137 x 107 (x 17 years) and I bring it in an array with the shape 14659 (137*107) x 17. That means I have 14659  pixels that have 17 observations.

For example: the linear regression over time SciPy needs two input arrays to perform: `linregress(x, y) where x is my vegetation data (17, ) and y = np.arange(len(x))`. 
I then iterate over all my pixels. And that is where I run out of memory.

**So my question is: how do I do my calculation with multiprocessing??** 
I tried that: 
 
I define my tile size = 1000, so I get 14 sub-arrays that are 1000x17 and one that is 659 x 17.
My regression I want to do for every column in my sub-array, so 1000 times 17 x 1.
 
For every sub-array:
`jobs = [(i, y_array) for i in sub-array]
slope, intercept, rvalue, pvalue, stderr = pool.map(stats.linregress, jobs)`
I get this error message: 
 
`multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '[LinregressResult(slope=0.0, intercept=8.0, rvalue=0.0, pvalue=1.0, stderr=126.49110640673517), LinregressResult(slope=-0.84790508832152001, intercept=8.0, rvalue=-0.17307790139143567, pvalue=0.50649559801778987, stderr=1.2458212006864782), (...) Reason: 'PicklingError("Can't pickle <class 'scipy.stats._stats_mstats_common.LinregressResult'>: attribute lookup scipy.stats._stats_mstats_common.LinregressResult failed",)'` 
So apparently it calculates something but failes loading or so... 

**Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?? Or has any suggestion how to solve the problem in a different way??**

Comment: You can try to create proxy function which calls `stats.linregress`, unpack `LinregressResult` into the simple touple and return it. This proxy function may be used in `pool.map` instead `stats.linregress` to avoid such error.

Comment: @StanislavIvanov I don't know about proxy functions... How do I create one?

Comment: @StanislavIvanov never mind :) got it and it is working... still taking incredibly long time!! Meaning that it is still running and not finished yet, so don't know if I will get a memory error again. 
Do you have any suggestions how to handle this big data?